# IIS 7.5 + AD DNS = no intranet subdomain names 4 u?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, iis, subdomain

Alright, hopefully this is a simple one..

We have a new server on our domain CMOT2.ourcompany.local
I want to host a few IIS sites on it and refer to them as WIKI.CMOT2.ourcompany.local etc.

I set up the IIS bindings, and also set up DNS CNAME aliases, but it doesn't resolve even after adding aliases I can resolve WIKI.CMOT2 in any way.  Just for completeness:

CNAME lives in cmot2 'folder' under ourcompany.local
Alias name is 'wiki'
FQDN for target host is cmot2.ourcompany.local

-- just noticed that if I nslookup cmot2 or cmot2.lacea.local, I get "non-existent domain".  Yet there is an A record for sitting in DNS.... and i am able to nslookup the other A-records..

Oh gods of expert administration, please advise!

Comment: So, you're using nslookup to lookup wiki.cmot2 and it's not resolving?

Answer (score 1):

Within the cmot2 folder you'll want an A record that points the IP address and has no name.